# Asynchronous leadership election

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous

The following code should be mostly OK, but I'm trying to avoid any stylistic problems or find anything that I overlooked.

The code is an implementation of asynchronous leadership election on a one way ring.

Parts of the implementation are a bit unnatural, because it has some forced features.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // initialization
    reset_sent_messages();
    srand(time(NULL));

    // prepare the array
    const unsigned total_nodes = 1000;
    vector< shared_ptr<Node> > nodes;
    nodes.reserve(total_nodes);

    // create nodes, put them into array
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < total_nodes; ++i)
        nodes.push_back(make_shared<Node>(i+1));

    // shuffle the nodes randomly
    random_shuffle(nodes.begin(),nodes.end());

    // connect the nodes
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < total_nodes-1; ++i)
        nodes[i]->connect(nodes[i+1]);
    nodes[total_nodes-1]->connect(nodes[0]);

    // prepare the futures to store the elected leader information
    vector< future<int> > leaders;
    for (auto i : nodes)
        leaders.push_back(i->get_leader());

    // run the threads with the main node logic
    for (auto i : nodes)
        thread([](shared_ptr<Node> node) { node->logic(); },i).detach();

    /* NOTE:
* For demonstrational purposes we are using promise<->future for final
* synchronization. This is a very unnatural model. Normaly we wouldn't
* detach the threads and use join().
*
* Do note that if a thread isn't detached and the thread variable (returned
* by thread call) is destroyed, the program will be immediately terminated.
* This is due to the fact, that such thread would be effectively leaked.
* Not running in detached mode, but incapable of joining the spawn thread.
*/

    // do the final synchronization (so that main doesn't end before the algorithm does)
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < total_nodes; i++)
    {
        if (leaders[i].get() != (int)total_nodes)
            throw runtime_error("Node didn't correctly detect it's leader.");
    }

    // final reports
    cout << "Asynchronous run finished." << endl;
    cout << "Total number of sent messages was : " << sent_messages() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**node.h**

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <future>
#include <atomic>

class Node
{

public:
    Node(unsigned node_id);

    /** \brief Put a new message into this nodes message buffer */
    void receive_message(int node_id, int distance);
    /** \brief Put a new message into this nodes message buffer */
    void receive_message(const std::pair<int,int>& message);

    /** \brief Connect this node to a next node in the circle */
    void connect(std::shared_ptr<Node> next);

    /** \brief Node logic */
    void logic();

    /** \brief Get the leader node id */
    std::future<int> get_leader();

private:
    /** \brief Try to pull one message from the buffer
*
* Non-blocking operation.
*/
    bool checkout_message(std::pair<int,int>& message);

    /** \brief Transmit one message to the connected node
*
* Blocking operation.
*/
    void transmit_message(int node_id, int distance);

    /** \brief Sub logic for processing the message
*
* Process the received message
* - detection of leader
* - detection of transiting state
* - trasmition of appropriate messages
*/
    void process_message(int n_id1, int n_id2);

    /** \brief Sub logic for transiting nodes
*
* Simple re-trasmit routine.
*/
    void transit_loop_step();

private:
    std::queue<std::pair<int,int> > p_message_buffer;
    std::mutex p_message_buffer_lock;

    std::weak_ptr<Node> p_next;
    std::mutex p_next_lock;

    int p_id;
    bool p_transit;
    bool p_done;
    std::promise<int> p_leader;
};

extern std::atomic<unsigned> message_count;

/** \brief Return count of sent messages */
unsigned sent_messages();

/** \brief Reinitialize the count of sent messages back to zero */
void reset_sent_messages();

#endif // NODE_H
```

**node.cpp**

```
#include "node.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

atomic<unsigned> message_count;

unsigned sent_messages() { return message_count; }
void reset_sent_messages() { message_count = 0; }

static mutex cout_lock;
// helper routine to output full lines from the algorithm
#define atomic_log(x) do { cout_lock.lock(); cout << x; cout_lock.unlock(); } while(0)

Node::Node(unsigned node_id) : p_id(node_id), p_transit(false), p_done(false)
{
    if (node_id == 0)
        throw range_error("Node id has to be greater than 0.");
}

void Node::receive_message(const pair<int,int> &message)
{
    // simple blocking implementation
    p_message_buffer_lock.lock();
    p_message_buffer.push(message);
    p_message_buffer_lock.unlock();
}

void Node::receive_message(int node_id, int distance)
{
    receive_message(make_pair(node_id,distance));
}

bool Node::checkout_message(std::pair<int,int>& message)
{
    // try to lock the message buffer for this thread
    // if it's locked, return false and wait a bit using yield
    if (!p_message_buffer_lock.try_lock())
    {
        this_thread::yield();
        return false;
    }

    // if we don't have any messages, yield and return false
    if (p_message_buffer.size() == 0)
    {
        p_message_buffer_lock.unlock();
        this_thread::yield();
        return false;
    }

    // we have a message, retrieve it, and remove from buffer
    message = p_message_buffer.front();
    p_message_buffer.pop();

    // don't forget to unlock
    p_message_buffer_lock.unlock();
    return true;
}

void Node::connect(shared_ptr<Node> next)
{
    // simple blocking implementation
    // only needed if connecting is done asynchronously
    p_next_lock.lock();
    p_next = next;
    p_next_lock.unlock();
}

void Node::transmit_message(int node_id, int distance)
{
    shared_ptr<Node> next;

    // if the node isn't connected yet, do blocking wait
    while(1)
    {
        p_next_lock.lock();
        next = p_next.lock();
        if (next) break;
        p_next_lock.unlock();
        this_thread::yield();
    }

    next->receive_message(node_id,distance);

    p_next_lock.unlock();

    ++message_count;
}

void Node::process_message(int n_id1, int n_id2)
{
    /* detection of leader
*
* - trasmit notification message telling other nodes
* - set self as leader
* - mark algorithm as done
*/
    if (n_id1 == p_id || n_id2 == p_id)
    {
        atomic_log("Node [ " << p_id << " ] self-declared leader." << endl);
        transmit_message(p_id,-1);
        p_leader.set_value(p_id);
        p_done = true;
    }
    /* detection of transit mode
*
* - mark the state
*/
    else if (n_id1 > p_id || n_id2 > p_id)
    {
        p_transit = true;
        atomic_log("Node [ " << p_id << " ] switched into transit mode." << endl);
    }
    /* if the node is not yet a leader, or in transit mode re-send the base messages */
    else
    {
        transmit_message(p_id,1);
        transmit_message(p_id,2);
    }
}

void Node::transit_loop_step()
{

    /* single step in transit mode
*
* - read a single message and re-transmit it to the next node
* - if the message is a leader notification, mark the leader node
*/
    pair<int,int> message;
    if (checkout_message(message))
        transmit_message(message.first,message.second);

    if (message.second == -1)
    {
        atomic_log("Node [ " << p_id << " ] recognized node [ " << message.first << " ] as the leader node." << endl);
        p_leader.set_value(message.first);
        p_done = true;
    }

    this_thread::yield();
}



void Node::logic()
{
    transmit_message(p_id,1);
    transmit_message(p_id,2);

    int message1 = 0, message2 = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        // if the algorithm is done, simply exit the thread
        if (p_done)
            return;

        // if in transit mode, run a single step of transmit logic
        if (p_transit)
        {
            transit_loop_step();
        }
        // if we have two messages, process them
        else if (message1 != 0 && message2 != 0)
        {
            process_message(message1,message2);
            message1 = 0; message2 = 0;
        }
        // if we don't have two messages, receive new messages
        else
        {
            pair<int,int> message;
            if (checkout_message(message))
            {
                if (message1 == 0)
                {
                    message1 = message.first;
                    if (message.second == 2 && message.first > p_id)
                        transmit_message(message.first,1);
                }
                else
                {
                    message2 = message.first;
                    if (message.second == 2 && message.first > p_id)
                        transmit_message(message.first,1);
                }
            }
        }
        this_thread::yield();
    }
}


future<int> Node::get_leader()
{
    return p_leader.get_future();
}
```

Comment: I'm really late here, but I thought I'd chime in and say it looks pretty good in general. I'd consider using a `std::unique_lock` though instead of manually calling `lock()` and `unlock()` on the mutex: eg, `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(p_message_buffer_lock);`. This guarantees that even in the case of an exception, the `mutex` will be unlocked.

Answer (score 5):

First, a general observation: you have a fair number of typos in your comments. Although the compiler doesn't check such things, I prefer to think of the comments as an integral part of the code, so even minor typos should be fixed.

- Random numbers

Right now, you're using `srand()` and `random_shuffle`. Although they were quite new when this question was written, at least if you were doing this today, you'd almost certainly want to use the "new" C++11 random number generators and `std::shuffle` instead.

- Locking

In a number of places, you have a pattern of locking, carrying out some action, then unlocking, such as:

```
void Node::receive_message(const pair<int,int> &message)
{
    // simple blocking implementation
    p_message_buffer_lock.lock();
    p_message_buffer.push(message);
    p_message_buffer_lock.unlock();
}
```

For such a case, I'd prefer to use `std::lock_guard`:

```
void Node::receive_message(const pair<int, int> &message) { 
    std::lock_guard guard(pmessage_buffer_lock);
    p_message_buffer.push(message);
}
```

This makes the code a little shorter and simpler (not a big deal, but not a bad thing by any means), but much more importantly it adds quite a bit of exception safety. If (for example) `p_message_buffer.push()` were to throw an exception, your code wouldn't unlock the lock, but this will.

- Magic numbers

You have magic numbers sprinkled rather liberally throughout the code. For example:

```
transmit_message(p_id,1);
transmit_message(p_id,2);
```

Until or unless you've looked at `transmit_message`, it may not be obvious that these are distances. Even if it's only useful from a documentation viewpoint, I'd at least consider creating a type specifically to represent a transmission distance, and probably give it an explicit constructor, so these would look something like:

```
transmit_message(p_id, hops(1));
transmit_message(p_id, hops(2));
```

This seems to me to make the code considerably more self-explanatory, even `hops` ends up doing essentially nothing other than giving a name/context for the numbers.

- shared_ptr

At least as I read things, the ring of nodes doesn't look like a particularly good use-case for `std::shared_ptr`. In particular, `shared_ptr` is intended to represent shared ownership. Using `shared_ptr` basically asserts that each node in the ring *owns* its successor node, which doesn't seem very accurate. Equally bad, a ring (or cycle in general) is a case where `shared_ptr` (or reference counting in general) doesn't work correctly. Each item in the cycle has a reference to the next, so every item always has a non-zero reference count (so they never get cleaned up) even when none of them is accessible any more.

- Comments redux

One other point about comments: right now it seems to me that the comments are really at too low a level to be particularly useful. Just for an obvious example, at some point I'd like to see an explanation of the actual algorithm this is intended to implement. That might well be only a sentence or two like: `send a message around the ring asking who's the leader. Iff the message arrives back at the originating node without any other node claiming leadership, then that node claims leadership."